# Google Chrome: How do I program new tab

Tags: google-chrome

How do I program Google Chrome to show thumbnail pages I choose in new tab "dashboard/desktop" insted of the " 6 most visited" .

Comment: Why don't you use the SpeedDial instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this chrome extension I believe it is what you are looking for.

[Speed Dial 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speed-dial-2/jpfpebmajhhopeonhlcgidhclcccjcik?hl=en)

Keep in mind you need to sign in with a google account for it to work properly.